# Making ImageView invisible from method

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created `HideImages()` function as shown below. The problem is, that running this code causes NullPointerExcpection. When I comment out the `setVisibility` lines, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
  ImageView img_w0, img_w1, img_w2;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageView img_w0 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img0);
    ImageView img_w1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    ImageView img_w2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);

    HideImages();

  }
  public void HideImages() {
    img_w0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    img_w1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    img_w2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make all the references of ImageView as Global as

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
  ImageView img_w0, img_w1, img_w2;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    img_w0 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img0);
     img_w1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
     img_w2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);

    HideImages();

  }
  public void HideImages() {
    img_w0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    img_w1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    img_w2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may case the problem because you had already initialize `ImageView` above the onCreate() method the why you declare here,

```
img_w0 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img0);
img_w1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
img_w2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problems is here. You're already declared the `ImageView` objects as globally. And, again you're declaring internally in `onCreate()`

So, just remove the declaration inside of `onCreate()` and run. Like below -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    img_w0 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img0);
    img_w1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    img_w2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was the problem!